# After refreshing data, the RecyclerView seems to move down on the screen

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-livedata, pagedlist

Using LiveData<PagedList> to display a recycler view that hits a Room database.  When I do a search on screen, the number of items returned is less, however, there seems to be a lot of extra white space between the recycler view and the other buttons.  The recycler view itself shrinks, and then moves down on the screen.

Here is the way it looks before the data is refreshed (before I do a search):

[image: normal]

Here is after:

[image: white space]

> Here is my adapter for the recyclerView:

```
class WorkPackagesRecyclerAdapter(
  private val onWorkPackageClickListener: OnClickWorkPackage
   ) : PagedListAdapter<Workpackage, 
 WorkPackagesRecyclerAdapter.WorkPackagesViewHolder>(
  REPO_COMPARATOR
) {


interface OnClickWorkPackage {
    fun clickWorkPackage(workPackageId: String)
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(viewGroup: ViewGroup, i: Int): WorkPackagesViewHolder {
    val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.context)
    val binding = inflate<ItemWorkPackageBinding>(
        inflater,
        R.layout.item_work_package,
        viewGroup,
        false
    )
    return WorkPackagesViewHolder(binding, viewGroup.context)
}


override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: WorkPackagesViewHolder, position: Int) 
{

    getItem(position)?.let {
        holder.bind(it)
    }

}

inner class WorkPackagesViewHolder(
    internal var binding: ItemWorkPackageBinding,
    internal val context: Context
) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root), KoinComponent {

    fun bind(data: Workpackage) {
        val itemWorkPackagesViewModel: ItemWorkPackagesViewModel by inject{ parametersOf(data)}
        this.binding.listItem.setOnClickListener {
            onWorkPackageClickListener.clickWorkPackage(data.id)
        }
        this.binding.viewmodel = itemWorkPackagesViewModel
        this.binding.executePendingBindings()
    }

}

companion object {
    private val REPO_COMPARATOR =
        object : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Workpackage>() {
            override fun areItemsTheSame(
                oldItem: Workpackage,
                newItem: Workpackage
            ): Boolean =
                oldItem.id == newItem.id

            override fun areContentsTheSame(
                oldItem: Workpackage,
                newItem: Workpackage
            ): Boolean =
                oldItem == newItem
        }


}
```

> Here is how I set up the PagedList:

```
val searchQuery: MutableLiveData<SearchAndSort> = MutableLiveData(
    SearchAndSort("",
        WorkpackagesRepository.Companion.SortedBy.WorkPackageNumber,
        AscendDescend.ASC))

var workPackagesList = Transformations.switchMap(searchQuery) { searchQuery ->
    val factory = workPackageStorageDao.searchWorkpackages(
        searchQuery.searchText,
        searchQuery.sortBy.type + " " + searchQuery.ascendDescend.text
    )
    val pagedListBuilder = LivePagedListBuilder<Int, Workpackage>(factory, pagingLimit)
    pagedListBuilder.build()
}
```

> Here is where I am observing the adapter:

```
    workPackagesViewModel.workPackagesList.observe(this, Observer { wpList ->
        wpList ?: return@Observer

        adapter = WorkPackagesRecyclerAdapter(this)
        adapter.submitList(wpList)
        binding.workPackagesRecyclerView.adapter = adapter
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

    })
```

> Here is the layout of the recycler view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<data>

    <variable
        name="viewModel"
        type="com.bechtel.pf.ui.workpackages.WorkPackagesViewModel" />
</data>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="727dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="1dp">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/search_bar_edit_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/work_package_margin"
        android:hint="@string/work_packages_search_hint"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/search_bar_magnifying_glass"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/work_package_margin"
        android:background="@drawable/icons_search"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="@dimen/work_package_search_guideline_start"

        />
    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/btnSortBy"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btnAscendDescend"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
        android:text="@string/work_packages_sort"
        />

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/btnAscendDescend"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btnFilterBy"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btnSortBy"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
        android:text="@string/work_packages_ascend"
        android:onClick="@{() -> viewModel.ascendingDescending()}"
        />

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/btnFilterBy"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btnAscendDescend"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/guideline"
        android:text="@string/work_packages_filter"/>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/workPackagesRecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="75dp"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnFilterBy">

    </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Anyone ever seen anything like this before?  I've also made sure that I am using layout_height = wrap_content in my recyclerview layout and item.xml files.

Screenshot inspector:

[image: layout inspector]

Comment: What does Android Studio's Layout Inspector show is going in that blank area? Something is strange overall, as you have `75dp` of top margin on that `RecyclerView`. Your first screenshot does not seem to show that margin, and your second screenshot shows much more than `75dp` of whitespace.

Comment: @CommonsWare It actually shows nothing going on in the white space.  The top margin (layout_topmargin) of the recycler view in the screen always stays at 197, no matter what the search results are.  However, the mTop property under Properties Table -> layout for the recyclerView shows 547 for the after search results, and 236 for all the results.  mTop is not a public property, so I don't know how this number is calculated.

Comment: `mTop` is based on the layout rules and reflects the actual position. In your layout, the `RecyclerView` top edge is anchored to the bottom of `btnFilterBy`. Are you sure `btnFilterBy` is not extending into that empty space?

Comment: @CommonsWare btnFilterBy is definitely not extending into that view.  Updated my question to show screen shot of layout inspector.

Comment: OK, I cannot explain why you are getting the results that you are. Personally, I'd set up a `Barrier` representing the bottom of your row of buttons (Sort, Descend, Filter) and have the `RecyclerView` tie its top to that `Barrier`. This covers you in case one of those buttons winds up being taller than the other two due to some combination of language translation and small screen size. It's theoretically possible that this will help your whitespace situation as well. Otherwise, is there anything else unusual with respect to the vertical axis? For example, do you have some pull-to-refresh code?

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks for all your help - I figured out the reason.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, it looks like I had set the recyclerview layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf was set to 'parent' and since the total height of the recyclerview shrunk when the number of items shrunk, it was moving the view to the bottom of the screen.  I also could get rid of the top margin attribute and the recycler view stayed below the buttons.  So now I have:

```
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/workPackagesRecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnFilterBy"/>
```

And it all looks good!

Comment: I was an idiot and had not noticed the `wrap_content` for the height. `wrap_content` is rarely a good idea for the height of things with varying content (e.g., `ListView`, `RecyclerView`, `ScrollView`). So, another approach would be to restore your bottom anchor, but set the height to `0dp`, to stretch the `RecyclerView` between the top and bottom anchors. Also, ideally, have your width set to `0dp` to stretch between the start and end anchor points, as `match_parent` technically is not supported for children of `ConstraintLayout`.